# Should I inform my Manager about my Future Studies plan

Tags: india, manager, leave-of-absence

I'm working as a Software Developer from 10 months and also preparing for ICWA. I have my exams in a few weeks and I need 2 weeks leave to attend them. Should I inform my Manager (I have to as I need leave, I have to mention the reason). I'm afraid that my Manager might say "If you are preparing for another one, you need not work here". So in what way should I apply for leave as well as convince him that I'm not going to leave the company

Thank You.

Comment: Do you *have* the time off you need to actually take these exams?  If so, there's no problem - take the time and do it.

Comment: I have half the time

Comment: That's a more difficult situation, and you should definitely mention it in your question.  You should also clarify what ICWA is - Acronyms are not clear to those who've never seen them before.

Comment: The last time I told my manager about my higher studies plan, it eventually ended up with me being at the top of the layoff hitlist, despite being a top performer for the previous *three* years.

Comment: What the hell is ICWA?

Comment: Can you tell us which country are you?

Comment: you are preparing for Indian Child Welfare Act? It's not very clear.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I inform my Manager?

You need two weeks off, so you have to tell your manager *something*.

If you accrued vacation time, presumably you can take a vacation without telling your manager the specifics about what you plan to do during your time off.

If you don't have enough vacation time available, you'll have to talk with your manager and ask permission. I believe honesty is usually the best policy, so you may need to get into more detail. You may want to think about how the ICWA could help your current company, and talk about that.